# Add record using ajax and modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to add records using modal, but it seems that i cant pass get value from ajax request,

(home.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveData(){
        var modsubj = $('#modalsubject').val();
        var modsect = $('#modalsection').val();
        var modstart = $('#modalstarttime').val();
        var modend = $('#modalendtime').val();
        var modday = $('#modalday').val();
       var user = $('#userID').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "modal.funcs.php?p=add",
            data: "subj="+modsubj+"&sect="+modsect+"&start="+modstart+"&end="+modend+"&day="+modday+"&user="+user

    }
</script>
```

(modal.funcs.php) I think the problem is the variable `$page` is not taking the GET value

```
<?php
    require_once("class.user.php");

    $auth_user = new USER();
    //add row

    $page = isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'';
    if($page=='add'){
        $modsubj = $_POST['subj'];
        $modsect = $_POST['sect'];  
        $modstart = $_POST['start'];
        $modend = $_POST['end'];
        $modday = $_POST['day'];
        $user_id = $_POST['user'];
        $auth_user->createSchedule($subj,$sect,$day,$strTime,$endTime,$user_id);
        $schedRow = $auth_user->readSchedule();
    }
    else if ($page == 'edit') {}

?>
```

Comment: did u noticed that u have made post request from ajax. I m not sure about php . but if ur php code accepting Get request , change ajax option type to Get

Comment: still not working, is it maybe the syntax of the $page variable?

Comment: i'm also not sure about php but seems like the parameters you are passing and getting is not with same name just like an example `modalsubject` you are getting but you have passed `subj` in your ajax call `data: "subj=` so make both same and others as well hope it'll work

Comment: Did you get any values in `$_POST` in modal.funcs.php?

Comment: did you notice that in the PHP you are looking in the POST array for keys that you never posted? For example `$modsubj` should be `$_POST['subj']`. In the ajax call you never define a `modalsubject` key to assign a value to but a `subj` one

Comment: What happens? What do you see in browser devtools? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`data: "subj="+modsubj+"&sect="+modsect+"&start="+modstart+"&end="+modend+"&day="+modday,`

to

`data: {"subj="+modsubj+"&sect="+modsect+"&start="+modstart+"&end="+modend+"&day="+modday},`